# Process Task - Unzipping files is failing

Tags: ssis-2012

I am using sql 2012 SSIS process task to unzip my files but I am getting the following error

[Execute Process Task] Error: 
In Executing "C:\Windows\System32\compact.exe" "x F:\Imports\RenLearn\'Roseville City School District'.zip -oF:\Imports\RenLearn\Roseville City School District" at "", 
The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

The two paths above are created as variables along with the path to  .  Any suggestions and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: More info I installed 7z zip and know the error I am getting is [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" "x F:\Imports\RenLearn.zip -oF:\Imports\RenLearn\RenImports" at "", The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0".

Comment: Since last post I have made the following changes. I switched out the x for an e in the above code.  Does it matter that I have two zipped files in that directory?  all file are going to the same destination. I am still getting '2' error.  It implies something wrong with one of my paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and I realised that I had copied the .exe file in the same folder as the .zip files because this resolved my problem in BIDS, but in Data Tools it seems like necessary to do that.. sounds little weird, but it worked for me so perhaps it will for you as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the "Working directory" property, you need to remove it to make the task work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in zip file name as the Execute process fails if the file contains special characters. Instead of spaces, use "_" and try it. Even the same issue I got later was sorted out by this approach.